# Display one column from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Display one or two column only from database in PHP.

I have a MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin. There is a table and in that table, there are multiple columns like salary, salary advance, etc. I want to display when user select salary it only show salary column, that is all data in the salary column. Here is my code. But it doesn't work. Please help.

```
<?Php
error_reporting(0);
include "config_1.php";
echo "<form  method=post action='viewexpensebagnan.php' >
    <select name='cn'>
       <option value='None'>choose option </option>
       <option value='salary'> salary </option>
       <option value='sa'> sa </option>
       <option value='house'> house </option>
       <option value='gr'> gr </option>
       <option value='bo'> bo </option>
       <option value='goutam'> goutam </option>
    </select>
    <input type=submit ><br>
</form>";
if(value=='salary')
{
    $query="select salary from expensebagnan";
    $count=$dbo->prepare($query);
    $count->execute();
    $no=$count->rowCount();

    echo "<table class='border' style='text-align:center;' width='100%'  >";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<tr><th>Salary</th></tr>";
    foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row){           
       echo "<tr><td>$row[salary]</td></tr>";
    }


    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

For example: If I select salary from the dropdown and submit then it will show only salary column data.

Comment: `if(value=='salary')` - explain what you think `value` should be in this place.

Comment: here value I gave from dropdown value. I want, if user select salary from dropdown it will show salary column if user select house then it will show house column. What will be the code?

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with this code - you should really go work through some beginner’s tutorials that teach you the basics of processing form values in PHP. It starts with that your select field does not have a name, so it won’t transmit a value _at all_ when this form gets submitted.

Comment: <select name='cn'> is this right?

Comment: `echo "</td><td>";` Odd place to put this line!

Comment: `<select>` elements need a `name="something"` attribute or they are not passed back to the php script.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ajax you can do it easily on change event of the drop-down list you can send the request with the value of drop down to the PHP code and PHP code will return you the values of the selected option.

**Eg.** Consider the following code (Put all code in one file, eg.index.php)

```
 <select id='value'>
   <option value='None'>choose option </option>
   <option value='salary'> salary </option>
   <option value='sa'> sa </option>
   <option value='house'> house </option>
   <option value='gr'> gr </option>
   <option value='bo'> bo </option>
   <option value='goutam'> goutam </option>
</select>
<button type=button value="submit" id="submit" > Submit </button>
<div id="showData"></div>
```

Now using jquery and ajax send the request to PHP as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "getValues.php",
            cache: false,
            type: "get",
            data: "value=" + $("#value").val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#showData").html(data);
            }
        });
    })
});

</script>
```

Your PHP code may look like this (**getValues.php**):

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['value']) && $_REQUEST['value'] == 'salary')
{
    $query = "select salary from expensebagnan";
    $count = $dbo->prepare($query);
    $count->execute();
    $no = $count->rowCount();

    echo "<table class='border' style='text-align:center;' width='100%'  >";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<tr><th>Salary</th></tr>";

    foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row){           
       echo "<tr><td>" . $row[salary] . "</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Suggestion `if(isset($_REQUEST['value'] ) && $_REQUEST['value'] == 'salary')`

Comment: Where I put this Ajax code?

Comment: In the same file. This is just for your reference, you can put your code into different files as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues with this code, but the thing why you cannot see the value from salary-key is that with this array-notation you need to wrap the array-access to curly-brackets, like this:

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['salary']}</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it does not work.

Comment: Actually `$row[salary]` is quite valid when used inside a double quoted string literal

Comment: @RiggsFolly Even `echo salary;` works, but technically it works by chance as it evaluates a non-defined constant `salary` to a string `salary`. But what check if you do this first:

`define ('salary', 'nope');`

Comment: Irrelevent! `echo "result = $row[xxx]";` is valid method (if little known) of outputting an array occurance in a double quoted string. Try it !!